# Twitter post an image, with url and some text from my website using Javascript

Tags: javascript, twitter, twitter-oauth

Let me just say that this is my 1st time using Twitter Javascript APIs.

I need to post an image, a URL link and some text on Twitter. I've already did this on Facebook successfully

**FACEBOOK Code**:

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    FB.init({ appId: 'APP_ID', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true });
</script>
```

and then you call the post message, checking if you are logged in

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
   function Foo() { 
     FB.login(function (response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            FB.ui({
                    method: 'feed',
                    name: 'Your Title',
                    link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
                    picture: 'http://someimage.com/image.jpg',
                    caption: 'Your Caption',
                    description: 'Your Description'
                }, 
                null
                );
         }
      } , { scope: 'your facebook access rights' });

      return false;
   }
```

The 1st line seems to take care of the login, app registration and authentication, which is great !!!

Now, back to Twitter I was hoping to get the same type of result:
    Share on Twitter

**TWITTER Code**:

```
<script>
    !function (d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];

        if (!d.getElementById(id)) {
            js = d.createElement(s);
            js.id = id;
            js.src = "https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }
    }(document, "script", "twitter-wjs");
</script>
```

This Twitter code gets the following **problems**:
1) Popup Blocker blocks the actual launch of the Tweeter dialog box
2) On IE the popup window (when allowed) actually open a new browser page as big as the current browser

So I went to read on the Tweeter Official URL https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/17110, and from there, it seems we need to take care of every single step/status individual event.

**QUESTION**: Is there a simple way to automatically post an image, url and text on Tweeter without encountering all these problems, and without having to deal with login, logout, post, posttext buttons ..and their various events?

Any help will be truly appreciated !!

Comment: Hey @SF Developer were you able to solve this issue.? Can you please guide me, I'm having same issue( how to post image,txt & url on twitter).? Thanks!